# Store domain in local storage and call it in href

Tags: javascript, html

I allow the user to store a domain in local storage (e.g. http://192.168.1.104).  My method of pulling the domain out of local storage is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  domain = localStorage['domain'];
  function DOMAIN(dive) {
    window.location=domain+dive;
  }
</script>
```

and I can open it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:DOMAIN('/');">CLICK HERE</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:DOMAIN('/');">CLICK HERE</a>
```

but I can't seem to get it to allow opening in a new tab (chrome v13).  It's driving me nuts, any suggestions?

Comment: did you try **target** attribute of anchor tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, but it's a little hacky and restless.  Make a dummy html document, say `/html/home.html` for instance.  Call the js-function inside the dummy doc:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Ripping Status</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    domain = localStorage['domain'] || '';
    function init() {
      window.location=domain+'/';
      document.getElementById( 'box' );             
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

where 'domain' is stored as, say, `http://192.168.1.101`.  Now, call `/html/home.html` inside the main html document via

```
<a href="/html/home.html">CLICK HERE</a>
```

and it allows right click > open new tab, window, etc as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:DOMAIN('/');" target="_blank">CLICK HERE</a>
```

Comment: Just opened up the same window I was in into a new tab.  I've seen that before but it doesn't seem to get me to open the js-link in a new tab though.

Comment: browser behave differently on the new tabs, you can adjust your browser to open new link in new tab instead in new window, also try **_newtab**.

Comment: Asad, this just opens the same window in a new tab and launches target domain in same tab, same as Aziz's reply.  But it does have right click open new tab (which duplicates existing tab).  

Also, the user shouldn't have to adjust their settings in their whole browser to make a js-href have same behavior as href="htttp://stuff", I would hope.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if this works for you:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(DOMAIN('/'));void(0);">CLICK HERE</a>
```

Comment: This open's a new tab with about:blank and the target tab with the user's domain.  Also, no right click to new tab open.